# Convert deprecated/PHP's 'other time zones' to standardized time zones

Tags: php, timezone

The PHP manual at https://www.php.net/timezones.others says to not use any of the time zones listed on that page besides `UTC` however the page does *not* provide a conversion map. My searches have only yielded unrelated/generic results.

Is there an existing list that converts deprecated time zones to standardized time zones that I can use to create proper associations in my database?

Comment: As per your described issue i found an article regarding this. Check this https://www.livelywebdesign.com/blog/2013/03/updating-php-deprecated-other-timezones-with-valid/ .

Comment: @ARVINDIT - The approach in that link assumes that a time zone has a single fixed offset, which is incorrect and will lead to wildly wrong mappings.  See "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP uses [IANA TZDB time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Some of the ones listed in the "others" page in the PHP docs are TZDB *links* to their canonical zones.  For example:  `Africa/Asmera` is a link to `Africa/Nairobi`.  While the latter is preferred, there's nothing wrong with using the former.  They will both continue to work, and continue to be represented [in the source data](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2020a/backward#L10).

Others on that page are "administrative zones".  For example, `Etc/GMT+11`, which has its sign intentionally inverted, representing a fixed offset of UTC-11.  These are valid, but should only be used in special cases, such as for ships at sea that are not in territorial waters.  All locations on land (and in territorial waters) should use a location-based zone name.

Yet others on those pages are in an older format that should be discouraged, but are still valid links.  For example `Cuba` is a valid link to `America/Havana`, but should be discouraged because it's not in the area/locality format.

Lastly, there are zones on that page that should be considered deprecated but do not have a link to a canonical zone.  For example `EST5EDT` is a zone that may have been used for "Eastern Time" - but cannot be cleanly mapped to a zone like `America/New_York` because it does not have any of the historical changes that occured in New York, and there are other entries in the Eastern time zone that had *different* histories than New York.

In short, you may be able to map *some* of those zones to their preferred representations by following links in the [TZDB sources](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), but some can't be mapped and others shouldn't.

Comment: Looks good though to support the project I was thinking of it would be about three weeks of dedicated work. I did come across the Time Zone Database while doing the initial research. This looks pretty solid so I'll accept it for now. I am of course open to any answers or updates as I know that time itself is *not* a static topic. Thank you!